# How can you show options in dojo dijit/Dialog and process responses with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dialog, dojo, dijit.dialog

I want to use dijit/Dialog to display dynamically generated options (maybe as checkboxes) and capture the user's response. For example, I generate three options to go in the dialog box:

```
Please pick an option:

Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
```

After the user indicates options 1, 2 and/or 3, I'd like to use JavaScript to collect those answers and send them (with xhr()) to the server for further processing.

I looked at http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Dialog.html, but I don't see any combination of the examples that would put all this together. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: could you please explain more the process chaining ! after selecting option you want to show diakog with the result of ajax ?

Comment: you need to add dojo dropdown to the Dialog and render the options. Upon user selection, read those values and send it to the server side

Comment: Boo Berr'ita, when the user picks an option, I'd like to dismiss the dialog box and display the result on the page (where the dialog is shown). So, on a form (say, a div with id "myForm") I'd like a button to post the dialog box. When the user selects an option, I want to pass that to the server with xhr(), dismiss the dialog box, and then display the results returned from the server on myForm. Alternatively, it could display the options, return the option selected to the form, and then have it use xhr() to pass it to the server and display the server results.